# How to show data to user inserted in db using queue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, events

I am working on a web scraping using `goutte`. I am providing a list of URL from a `.txt` file. I have created a job which do the scraping and save the data in DB table.

I want to show the data to the user as a job gets done.
Here is a condition that I can't use ajax.

Please help me find out the solution for this. Where an event shown happened when an entry was added in DB table and also, append data in front-end table but user should never get blocked.

Comment: The answer is [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting), using something like [beyondcode/laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) and [laravel/echo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use ajax the only other option is push notifications, which is a better option anyway. In laravel you can do this with [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/broadcasting). In order to use broadcasting you need another service that will use web sockets to push the notifications, because (in general) you can't use web sockets with php. Laravel supports [several services for broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/broadcasting#configuration) out of the box, like pusher. Another good option is [socket.io](https://socket.io/).